# Testing React Router with @testing-library-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

Good morning, it's my first time seeking answers related to programming, but I've already hit a dead end here. I've scoured foreign websites, documentation, questioned ChatGPT (was not very helpful), so maybe I'll find the answer here. I'm currently working on a simple React application, just testing all the settings for now. I've added React Router, and it's working perfectly. However, I'm having trouble writing tests that would check the transition of a user from one subpage to another. My test file looks like this:

```
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { fireEvent } from '@testing-library/dom';
import Context from './Context';
import { RouterProvider, createMemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { routes } from './Router';
 
describe('App component', () => {
  it('renders App', async () => {
    const router = createMemoryRouter(routes, { initialEntries: ['/login'] });
 
    render(
      <Context>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </Context>
    );
 
    const btn = screen.getByText('Go back to main page');
    expect(btn).toBeVisible();
    userEvent.click(btn);
 
 
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(window.location.pathname).toBe('/');
      expect(btn).toBeVisible();
    });
 
    screen.debug();
  });
});
```

And now - the router loaded correctly - meaning, if I manually set the initialEntries to the home page "/" it tests the home page, and if it's a subpage, it tests the subpage; regular tests work flawlessly. But if the user clicks 'userEvent.click(btn)' and should be redirected to the home page, after using 'screen.debug()', nothing changes, and the previous page remains. To make things even more interesting in this test:

```
await waitFor(() => {
    expect(window.location.pathname).toBe('/');
    expect(btn).toBeVisible();
  });
```

Both tests pass, meaning the path is correctly updated, but the 'old' page from the previous path is still displayed (there wouldn't be this button on the home page).

Intuitively, the problem may lie in asynchronicity, meaning that the event is executed correctly, but the new page hasn't had time to render yet, so it displays the old one. However, I've tried various approaches like inserting await, using waitFor functions, setTimeout, and so on, but I still couldn't achieve the desired effect.

If anyone has any ideas, I would be grateful. I hope I've written this in a reasonably clear manner.

Best regards.